# SOLVED: Select by <div>linktext</div> not working tried everything

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Its a popup overlay the div looks like this:

`<div class="tutorial-button tutorial-button-ok tt-close">Later</div>`

source code looks like this:

`<a class="match-button match-button-close" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="matchingLayerClose();">
       <i class="material-icons match-button-icon">close</i> Later 
</a>`

I would like to findElement either by cssSelector, className or 'Later' link text, doesnt matter

I tried:

`By.className("tutorial-button tutorial-button-ok tt-close");`

`By.cssSelector("div[class='tutorial-button tutorial-button-ok tt-close']");`

`By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Later')]"))`

`By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Later')]"))`

which works fine on other elements. pls help

Comment: Can you please clear your question a bit more?

Comment: You need to explain what "doesn't work" means more specifically. You need to edit your question and add the error/exception messages for each attempt. I can tell you the first one, `By.className()`, won't work because you put 3 class names when you can only use 1. The second one is not very CSS-like... it should be `div.tutorial-button.tutorial-button-ok.tt-close`.  The third probably didn't work because there are several elements that match that locator. The 4th probably didn't work because there's other stuff in the `A` tag that messes with `contains()`.

Comment: Try `By.xpath("//div[.='Later']")` or maybe `By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Later')]")`. If those don't work, it's probably inside an `IFRAME`. Once you've investigated all this, edit your question and add the results.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge! Especially @JeffC for making things clear. this stuff is pretty new to me.

Comment: `By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Later')]"` worked after all i just wrapped it in conditional. i feel stupid now

Comment: `By.cssSelector("div.tutorial-button.tutorial-button-ok.tt-close")` found element aswell!! but said "element not interactable"

Comment: I added my comment as an answer since you said that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a CSS selector like

```
div.tutorial-button.tutorial-button-ok.tt-close
```

or an XPath like

```
//div[.='Later']
//div[contains(.,'Later')]
```